# Why do cables not arc/spark when being removed or reconnected on a car battery terminal?

Tags: batteries, cables, automotive, spark, arc

For example, when removing a car battery, the negative cable is to be removed first and reconnected last, but why does it not arc/spark in any of those scenarios? The circuit is complete, so why isn't there any sparking? My wild guess would be if a car is turned off no power is being transmitted in the circuit, but there are electrical components utilizing power (i.e., the clocks, security system, automatic locks, etc.), so how is no sparking or arcing occurring possible upon disconnect/reconnect of a negative battery cable?

Comment: I see sparks when doing that.

Comment: There will be sparks if you try hard enough. There are always capacitors and inductors present in the car's electronics and these cause the sparking by their charging (capacitors) or back EMF (inductors).

Comment: @FakeMoustache Define "try hard enough". Does that mean if I rub them harder or something, it will happen?

Comment: It means disconnecting and waiting for the capacitors to discharge, then connect but slowly and gently and make the initial contact area as small as possible, use a pointy part of the connector, not the flat parts. Same for disconnecting, try it slowly and you might see a spark.

Comment: Probably not seeing sparks because the current is very low, so the sparks are not very energetic. It doesn't matter which terminal you disconnect first. See RoyC's answer for an explanation of why it is recommended to disconnect negative first, and connect it last.

Comment: it sparks you just cant see it.  Just like when you do ESD damage to digital electronics, you can destroy stuff with out seeing or feeling those sparks.  The sparks are there you might need the right equipment and darkness of ambient light to see it, depending.

Answer (score 5):

You get the same spark if you disconnect the ground cable first. The amount of sparking or arcing depends on the amount of current flowing in the circuit.

You disconnect the ground cable first and connect it last so that if your spanner contacts a piece of the car body work you do not get a really big spark. You would get this spark in these circumstances if you connected/disconnected the positive last/first shorting out the battery.

Comment: How is connecting the ground spanner last going to prevent/dim the spark? You just said that it depend on the amount of current in the circuit, so it shouldn't matter. Or maybe there is another reason behind this observation. I would say that you'll get the same spark but I've never did the test.

Comment: @HatimB Please do not try the spanner on positive terminal, connect to bodywork with the negative cable connected test. You will probably get hurt, I have done it and got away with it. But believe me you will get a spark.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience, I won't try it. But how are they different? It is the same circuit, the same everything, how is connection order going to affect the spark's damage capability?

Comment: @HatimB Consider what happens if you remove the +ve terminal with a spanner while the -ve terminal is connected: turn, turn, turn, slip oops the spanner touches some metalwork which means a short circuit across the battery and a *big* spark from the spanner to the metalwork, which could weld the spanner on. If you disconnect the -ve terminal first, there will be no short circuit in that scenario. N.B. there may be some +ve earth vehicles around still.

Comment: No it is not the same circuit. You are introducing a difference in the circuit. This is a fault condition where the terminal you are working on is connected to the car bodywork, the car bodywork is connected to the negative battery terminal so you are either introducing a short across an already connected circuit which does nothing or a short across the battery which produces a crack a flash and a lot of heat.

Comment: @HatimB You're right. If it's the current, then why would it matter? I'm not asking why negative or positive cables should be connected first or last, I'm asking why is there no spark/arc when there is a complete circuit. If the amount of current determines this, how much current would produce a spark large enough to see?

Answer (score 0):

A spark appears when the dieletric (here, the air) breaks down because the voltage is too high between the electrodes. A battery car is supposed to be ~12V. This is not a lot, so the end of the cable has to be really close to the battery terminal for a spark to occur. But it could. It just has much better chances to be seen with a few kV.

Comment: There is always some **inductance** in the car's circuit and that can cause **back EMF** when you **disconnect** the car's circuits and that back EMF can be several kV. Try it on your bench with a battery and the coil of a relay, it is quite easy to generate a small spark.

Comment: @FakeMoustache there is some inductance, but there is also a lot of leakage between the positive and negative supply lines, due to the components present in the car. So the voltage doesn't have much chance to build up like that. What you say is true, but for a very short time only. So it all depends on the conditions.

Comment: True, it all depends. But when I do disconnect a car battery for example I do make sure I'm not touching both connections at once when disconnecting to avoid getting a shock. Indeed the back EMF might not always be enough for a spark but it can easily be enough for a small "tingle" and I want to avoid those when I can.

Comment: You don't need high voltage in order to get a spark.

Comment: So is it the lack of current or volts, or both?